# Non-alcoholic mint julep?

Tags: substitutions, alcohol

Can I substitute Bourbon in [this recipe](http://projects.washingtonpost.com/recipes/2008/04/30/mint-julep/)? Lemonade would make it too sour. Water would make it too watery.

I know this isn't exactly cooking per se, but the reason behind this is that I have a BUNCH of left over mint that's probably a day from going bad and I'm scrambling to

Comment: As far as the second paragraph goes, we already have that question: [What can I do with extra mint?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3135)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the world of cocktails, the term for creating a drink with no alcohol is "virgin".

If you google "[virgin mint julep](https://www.google.com/search?q=virgin%20mint%20julep)", you will find recipes to try to simulate the beverage without bourbon.   They employ a variety of strategies, but ginger ale, lemon juice, or lemonade seem to come up fairly frequently, alone or in combination.